# Codeigniter Cannot save hashed password to database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, passwords

I cannot save hashed password to my 'users' table, but if it's not hashed, the password saved. Can everybody help me?

**Controller**

```
public function add()
{
    $this->data['title'] = 'add new user';
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/add';      

    $validate = $this->user->validate;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($validate);

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
        $this->user->insert(array(
            'name'          =>  $this->input->post('name'),
            'email'         =>  $this->input->post('email'),
            'password'      =>  $this->user->hash($this->input->post('password'))
        ));

        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', msg_success('Data Saved'));
        redirect('admin/user', 'refresh');
    }

    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

**my Hash function in user_model**

```
public function hash($string)
{
    return hash('md5', $string . config_item('encryption_key'));
}
```

What's wrong with my code, or is there any other way to do it without any library? or How you do it basically to do this using codeigniter? Thanks

**EDIT**

this is my *insert function* from MY_Model

```
public function insert($data, $skip_validation = FALSE)
{
    if ($skip_validation === FALSE)
    {
        $data = $this->validate($data);
    }

    if ($data !== FALSE)
    {
        $data = $this->trigger('before_create', $data);

        $this->_database->insert($this->_table, $data);
        $insert_id = $this->_database->insert_id();

        $this->trigger('after_create', $insert_id);

        return $insert_id;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Im using [Jamie Rumbelow Base Model](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model) for my base model, and I have follow his tutorial for insert into database

Comment: what is the type of password field. is it varchar? make it text or do something to meet your requirements

Comment: @raheelshan its varchar with 128 length, I think the problem is not the field type, because if Im not hashed my password, it's saved into database :(

Comment: 128 is nothing to save password try changing it to 255. Or use text field

Comment: @raheelshan Ok, I have try to change them into varchar(255) and text, but its also not working, am I miss CI helpers or library for doing this? I have load session library, and set up the encryption key

Comment: Can you supply us with the insert() function from your model?

Comment: Try dumping the array before you insert, so you can see if the password is being hashed. Or, try renaming the hash() function.

Comment: @Craig I have rename the hash() function to xhash() and dumped the array and the password field is hashed like so: [password] => d14aa43dc0122af6fdd8eab3c0c4cdf4 ...

Comment: Try and insert it yourself, without the help of the extended model. It seems strange that the password is being hashed, but it's getting lost.